# Как можно одному объекту добавить другой объект

Tags: javascript

Для графиков использую chart.js, у меня есть 6 графиков у которых `option` одинаковый для всех только отличается название графика `title`. Я вынес в `defaultOption` все настройки которые есть у других и к этим настройкам хочу добавлять только `title` нужного графика, как можно `receivedOption` добавить к `defaultOption` ?

```
let defaultOption = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true
    }
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    fontSize: 24
  }
};

let receivedOption = {
  title: {
    text: 'Received payments'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
let defaultOption = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true
    }
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    fontSize: 24
  }
};

let receivedOption = {
  title: {
    text: 'Received payments'
  }
};

const options = {
  ...defaultOption,
  title: {...defaultOption.title, ...receivedOption.title}
}

console.log(options)
```

Просто `{...defaultOption, ...receivedOption}` не подойдет, так как у обоих есть св-во `title`. В этом случае, второй объект полностью перезапишет значение из первого